# Faster way to know if a widget belongs to the widget-tree

Tags: python, kivy

I want to know if a widget is belongs to the widget tree.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory


KV_CODE = '''
BoxLayout:
    Widget:
        Widget:
            id: me
'''


def belongs_to_the_tree(widget) -> bool:
    parent = widget.parent
    try:
        # Looks like `Window.parent` is `Window` itself,
        # so use it as loop-condition.
        while parent is not widget:
            widget = parent
            parent = widget.parent
        return True
    except AttributeError:
        return False


class SampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV_CODE)
    def on_start(self):
        root = self.root
        me = root.ids.me
        assert belongs_to_the_tree(me)
        root.parent.remove_widget(root)
        assert not belongs_to_the_tree(me)
        assert not belongs_to_the_tree(Factory.Widget())
        print('all assertions are done')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SampleApp().run()
```

The code above looks working fine, but I wonder if there is a faster way than it... like relying on an implementation detail.

## Versions

- Kivy v2.0.0rc2, git-420c8e2, 20200601
- Python 3.8.1

## performance comparision

As John Anderson suggested, `get_root_window()` can be used. So I compared it to mine.

```py
from timeit import timeit
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window

assert Window.parent is Window

def belongs_to_the_tree_ver1(widget) -> bool:
    parent = widget.parent
    try:
        # Looks like `Window.parent` is `Window` itself,
        # so use it as loop-condition.
        while parent is not widget:
            widget = parent
            parent = widget.parent
        return True
    except AttributeError:
        return False


def belongs_to_the_tree_ver2(widget) -> bool:
    parent = widget.parent
    while parent is not widget:
        if parent is None:
            return False
        widget = parent
        parent = widget.parent
    return True


def belongs_to_the_tree_ver3(widget) -> bool:
    return widget.get_root_window() is not None


def create_widget_tree(depth:int):
    if depth < 1:
        return None
    root = current = Widget()
    for __ in range(depth - 1):
        child = Widget()
        current.add_widget(child)
        current = child
    return (root, current)


for belongs_to_window in (True, False):
    print(f'---- Window[{belongs_to_window}] ----')
    for depth in range(1, 10):
        print('depth:', depth)
        root, bottom = create_widget_tree(depth)
        if belongs_to_window:
            Window.add_widget(root)
        print('ver1:', timeit(lambda: belongs_to_the_tree_ver1(bottom), number=10000))
        print('ver2:', timeit(lambda: belongs_to_the_tree_ver2(bottom), number=10000))
        print('ver3:', timeit(lambda: belongs_to_the_tree_ver3(bottom), number=10000))
```

```
---- Window[True] ----
depth: 1
ver1: 0.053809361008461565
ver2: 0.05703714000992477
ver3: 0.09484150097705424
depth: 2
ver1: 0.06821069598663598
ver2: 0.06333867699140683
ver3: 0.11188063403824344
depth: 3
ver1: 0.05221751698991284
ver2: 0.06236394098959863
ver3: 0.14249391900375485
depth: 4
ver1: 0.07111674797488376
ver2: 0.05825958802597597
ver3: 0.16919472097652033
depth: 5
ver1: 0.06647598498966545
ver2: 0.05714027502108365
ver3: 0.1917542329756543
depth: 6
ver1: 0.06825654400745407
ver2: 0.06046949198935181
ver3: 0.2067307039978914
depth: 7
ver1: 0.07003391603939235
ver2: 0.06269123003585264
ver3: 0.22394260700093582
depth: 8
ver1: 0.06261502200504765
ver2: 0.06446945498464629
ver3: 0.24196087603922933
depth: 9
ver1: 0.06388465402415022
ver2: 0.06795549503294751
ver3: 0.26855201995931566
---- Window[False] ----
depth: 1
ver1: 0.05611837498145178
ver2: 0.05091271601850167
ver3: 0.06252052402123809
depth: 2
ver1: 0.058835825009737164
ver2: 0.05442504899110645
ver3: 0.09280205494724214
depth: 3
ver1: 0.061204864003229886
ver2: 0.0558167599956505
ver3: 0.10734522802522406
depth: 4
ver1: 0.06451991299400106
ver2: 0.05160770198563114
ver3: 0.13290800602408126
depth: 5
ver1: 0.06612819898873568
ver2: 0.0550711999530904
ver3: 0.15143772203009576
depth: 6
ver1: 0.06800857203779742
ver2: 0.05633674800628796
ver3: 0.17342579300748184
depth: 7
ver1: 0.07648328202776611
ver2: 0.05929249798646197
ver3: 0.19549044501036406
depth: 8
ver1: 0.0797340459539555
ver2: 0.06139807298313826
ver3: 0.23101057397434488
depth: 9
ver1: 0.07286432798719034
ver2: 0.07131565903546289
ver3: 0.2374060670263134
```

Comment: Try using the `Widget` method `get_root_window()`. I think it will return `None` if the `Widget` is not in the currently displayed tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`belongs_to_the_tree_ver2()` in the performance comparision might be the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Widget` method `get_root_window()` like this:

```
def belongs_to_the_tree(widget) -> bool:
    return widget.get_root_window() is not None
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that method, but looks like it's quite slower than mine. (updated the post)

Comment: The `get_root_window()` method uses recursion, which is likely the cause of the slower performance.